# Xamarin forms Hardware Acceleration for Emulator Performance. (Taking a lot time to deploy)

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator

**Using Visual Studio Community 2017 and Xamarin Forms.**

May be this a possible duplicate question. But Believe me I have tried almost all options as much as possible.

I tried following best even with solutions provided:-
1. armeabi-v7a processor. But still it gets about 30+ minutes to reach delpoy and no resolution even after that.
2. Installing HAXM gives error as Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: is No
3. I tried running many times without Hardware Acceleration but then it is as if a endless going on process, for half an hour to hour and still not reaching actual delpoy.
4. Windows Live Player is not working. With lot of search on google found it has in-built-bugs still.

All the searched posts are major around 1-2 years back which I saw. So my question is that is there any resolution for this issue is found. Which even takes 15 minutes to deploy but gives me running my app on android emulator?

Thank you very much in advance.
Please note:- I have attached images for more clarification.
1. systeminfo
2. My Laptop Properties
3. Android Device Added

[image: systeminfo]

[image: My Computer Properties]

[image: Emulator Device Created]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable Vt-x in your system BIOS?

Comment: WOW! In just one attempt only resolved the entire issue. Now within 3 minutes its easily going on to deploy and that too with x86! Nothing I have to modify now to my original settings. Lovely! Thanks a ton. You saved my so much time and quick resolution. Sorry for delay to reply, was just checking my app running smoothly on emulator.

Comment: happy to help :) @YeshwantMudholkar

Comment: Absolutely Super Answer. Only to clear others in my PC its Intel Virtualization Technology which I had to enabled to true in Bios. Once again a lot of thanks. You really helped me very timely and exactly point to point.